# secure session cookie in servicestack

Tags: servicestack, session-cookies

Can anyone tell me how to get ServiceStack to use secure attribute on the session cookies so that the cookie is only sent on https based requests. This is important for helping to prevent session hijacking. My tests so far show that if ServiceStack authentication in done on a https website it still sets the cookies to no be secure meaning if there are any http requests in the site the cookies could be captured.

Is there a setting or config to change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Config.UseSecureCookies` option to tell ServiceStack to add a Secure cookie for SessionIds in HTTPS requests:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig { 
  UseSecureCookies = true
});
```

Comment: This seems to be named `UseSecureCookies` now.

Comment: This is supposed to add the Secure flag? I'm still getting `set-cookie: X-UAId=1; expires=Mon, 04 Jun 2040 08:06:27 GMT; path=/; samesite=none; httponly` returned from `/auth/Credentials` and then Chrome complains that _A cookie ... was set with `SameSite=None` but without `Secure`._

Comment: @specimen is this over https?

Comment: It's to the Vue development server, so it's not.

Comment: @specimen it's working by design, secure cookies should only be sent over a secure channel.

Comment: My bad, but calling it now at https and then I'm getting some cookies with secure and some without. All in the same response from /auth/Credentials:

```set-cookie: ss-id=XdireSWgFqd4yh52bmeC; path=/; secure; samesite=none; httponly
set-cookie: ss-pid=KOq9MXhjgcMVyiOGWPl7; expires=Mon, 04 Jun 2040 08:31:14 GMT; path=/; secure; samesite=none; httponly
set-cookie: ss-opt=temp; expires=Mon, 04 Jun 2040 08:31:14 GMT; path=/; samesite=none; httponly
set-cookie: X-UAId=1; expires=Mon, 04 Jun 2040 08:31:14 GMT; path=/; samesite=none; httponly```

Comment: @specimen clear out your cookies and start again, only accessing from https.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215284/discussion-between-specimen-and-mythz).